# how to parse LDAP into Ruby data?

Tags: ruby, ldap

I'm trying consume a LDAP database of users that I have and I already made some previous text processing so that I have a text like this:

```
uid: angelica
cn: Angelica Turaca
homeDirectory: /home/exaluno/angelica
mail: angelica@linux.ime.usp.br,

uid: ljunior
cn: Lourinaldo Anastacio da Silva Junior
homeDirectory: /home/exaluno/ljunior
mail: ljunior@linux.ime.usp.br,

uid: acvm
cn: Ana Cristina Vieira de Melo
homeDirectory: /home/prof/acvm
mail: acvm@linux.ime.usp.br,
```

It contains all data that I want to have. I just would like to transform it into something like:

```
users[0]['uid'] #angelica
users[1]['mail'] #ljunior@linux.ime.usp.br
```

What would be the easiest way?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. We'd like to see the minimum example of what you tried rather than write an entire script from scratch that might or might not fit what you've written. We could also inadvertently end up duplicating your code, wasting our time. "What would be the easiest way" kinda depends on what you've already tried, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but some regexes do the job quickly:

```
obj = {}
users = []

ldap_file.each_line do |line|
  if line =~ /([^:]+): (.*?),?$/
    obj[$1] = $2
    if line =~ /,$/
      users << obj
      obj = {}
    end
  else
    warn "Failed to match: #{line}"
  end
end
```

A more elegant solution (though you need the whole text in memory at once)

```
users = ldap_text.split(/,\s*/m).map do |grp|
  grp.each_line.map { |line| line.strip.split(/:\s*/) }.to_h
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str =<<_
uid: angelica
cn: Angelica Turaca
homeDirectory: /home/exaluno/angelica
mail: angelica@linux.ime.usp.br,

uid: ljunior
cn: Lourinaldo Anastacio da Silva Junior
homeDirectory: /home/exaluno/ljunior
mail: ljunior@linux.ime.usp.br,

uid: acvm
cn: Ana Cristina Vieira de Melo
homeDirectory: /home/prof/acvm
mail: acvm@linux.ime.usp.br,
_

users = str.split(/\n\n+/).each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
  a << s.each_line.with_object({}) do |line,h|
    k,v = line.strip.split(/:\s*/)
    h[k] = v
  end
end
  #=> [{ "uid"=>"angelica", "cn"=>"Angelica Turaca",
  #      "homeDirectory"=>"/home/exaluno/angelica", 
  #      "mail"=>"angelica@linux.ime.usp.br,"},
  #    { "uid"=>"ljunior", "cn"=>"Lourinaldo Anastacio da Silva Junior",
  #      "homeDirectory"=>"/home/exaluno/ljunior",
  #      "mail"=>"ljunior@linux.ime.usp.br,"},
  #    { "uid"=>"acvm", "cn"=>"Ana Cristina Vieira de Melo",
  #      "homeDirectory"=>"/home/prof/acvm", "mail"=>"acvm@linux.ime.usp.br,"}]   

users[0]['uid']   #=> "angelica"
users[1]['mail']  #=> "ljunior@linux.ime.usp.br,"
```

If you don't want the comma at the end of the last return value, that's easily dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

I used a solution described in [Parsing a string of the form “key1=value1;key2=value2;” into a Hash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80572/parsing-a-string-of-the-form-key1-value1key2-value2-into-a-hash) using [Hash[[key, value], …]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) definition since *Ruby 1.9*

```
def to_hash(str)
  Hash[
    str.split(';').map do |pair|
      k, v = pair.split('=', 2)
      [k, v.to_i]
    end
  ]
end
```